# Data Binding not happening between service and controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, service

I am trying to use a service instead of a factory to perform two way data binding, I have seen may tutorials online on using a factory but I prefer using a service instead of a factory, so far I have come up with the following pattern to perform the binding but, on doing console.log() i found that the data from the service doesn't bind to the data on the controller.

```
 controller: ['$scope','LeadsService','ServiceVehicleModels', function($scope, LeadsService, ServiceVehicleModels) {            

        $scope.colorList = ServiceVehicleModels.colors;
        $scope.yearsList = ServiceVehicleModels.years;


        $scope.$watch(function() { return ServiceVehicleModels.colors }, function(data) {                                
            return $scope.colorList = data.colors;                   
        },true);
```

};

Here is my service code 
exports.service = function() {

```
this.colors = [];
this.years = [];

this.trims = [];

var scope = this;   

this.setColors = function(colorsArr) {
    scope.colors = colorsArr;       
};

this.setYears = function(yearsArr) {
    scope.years = yearsArr;
};
```

};

What changes do i need to make to make the data binding work?

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in watcher. This should solve bindings:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return ServiceVehicleModels.colors }, function(colors) {                                
            return $scope.colorList = colors;                   
        },true);
```